# How springSecurityFilterChain Skips Authentication for already logged in requests

Tags: spring, spring-security, httpwebrequest

I have been working on spring security, and all is working well. But I just went debugging how it works. All filters are configured for springsecurityfilterchain via http namespace. One of them is Authentication filter for providing authentication. What I found is when a new login request comes(no previous session) the Authentication filter is invoked, but when the request comes for already logged in user, i.e, a session existing, then the authenticationfilter is not invoked. I coudn't find where and how the 'springsecurity' skips this authentication for already logged in requests. Please help me understand this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the SessionManagementFilter takes care of this:

```
        if (!securityContextRepository.containsContext(request)) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication != null && !authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication)) {
         // The user has been authenticated during the current request, so call the session strategy
            try {
                sessionAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(authentication, request, response);
            } catch (SessionAuthenticationException e) {
                // The session strategy can reject the authentication
                logger.debug("SessionAuthenticationStrategy rejected the authentication object", e);
                SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
                failureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, e);

                return;
            }
            // Eagerly save the security context to make it available for any possible re-entrant
            // requests which may occur before the current request completes. SEC-1396.
            securityContextRepository.saveContext(SecurityContextHolder.getContext(), request, response);
        } else {
         // No security context or authentication present. Check for a session timeout
            if (request.getRequestedSessionId() != null && !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {
                if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("Requested session ID " + request.getRequestedSessionId() + " is invalid.");
                }

                if (invalidSessionStrategy != null) {
                    invalidSessionStrategy.onInvalidSessionDetected(request, response);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Of course there's more here than meets the eye. The Authentication is stored in a ThreadLocal:

> In Spring Security, the responsibility for storing the SecurityContext between requests falls to the SecurityContextPersistenceFilter, which by default stores the context as an HttpSession attribute between HTTP requests. It restores the context to the SecurityContextHolder for each request and, crucially, clears the SecurityContextHolder when the request completes. You shouldn't interact directly with the HttpSession for security purposes. There is simply no justification for doing so - always use the SecurityContextHolder instead.

So it's the responsibility of SecurityContextPersistenceFilter to load context data (and erase it later), other modules down the filter chain will make decisions based on this data. (for example skip or do authentication via the usermanager service)

I'm not a SpringSecurity developer, so take this info as an educated guess only :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a handled by a combination of three `Filters`:

- [`SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/context/SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.html) which gets the [`Authentication`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html)
  from the session (if it exists) and puts it in the thread local `SecurityContextHolder` so other filters can see it.
- If no `Authentication` is in the [`SecurityContextHolder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html) the [`AnonymousAuthenticationFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.html) adds an [`AnonymousAuthenticationToken`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AnonymousAuthenticationToken.html) to the `SecurityContextHolder`.
- [`FilterSecurityInterceptor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/intercept/FilterSecurityInterceptor.html) throws
  an exception if the `Authentication` in the `SecurityContextHolder` does not have the proper
  permissions (for example `ROLE_USER`) for the current request.

Answer (score 0):

When a request is made to a secured object, SessionManagementFilter will look into SecurityContextRepository. If its content matches the SecurityContextHolder, it assumes that that user is authenticated before (like remember-me or pre-authentication).
If the repository contains security context, this filter does nothing.
If it has nothing and ThreadLocal contains an Authentication Object, it assumes that previous filters have authenticated this user somehow.

Answer (score 0):

`httpSessionIntegrationFilter` takes care of this. It is responsible for maintaining the session between the requests from the same user.

Answer (score 0):

Ok question can be still actual so will try to answer:

From my own research it does not look like "skipping".

First of all spring generates filter chain. If you use spring boot - just enable debug and in booting log you can see whole filters chain.

Each request goes through this chain - doesn't matter what you configured in "configure" method and HttpSecurity object. So your phrase

> What I found is when a new login request comes(no previous session) the Authentication filter is invoked, but when the request comes for already logged in user, i.e, a session existing, then the authenticationfilter is not invoked

isn't really true. Authentication filter will be invoked but inside doFilter exist checking request and if URL isn't for login - filter calls doFilter and "returns". 
Example: 
you configured LoginPage filter to "/login POST". You can send POST request to /login one-by-one with different credentials and your app will rewrite session to new user. So if you don't want to allow user to do it - you can override filter and some logic to check session if user logged in and just call doFilter.